# Unable to enter ID in twitter

Tags: selenium

I'm running the below selenium code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class twitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        FirefoxDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver();
        fd.get("https://twitter.com/?lang=en");
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signin-email']")).sendKeys("Hello");
    }
}
```

But i'm getting the below error.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'U0138039-TPL-A', ip: '192.168.1.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: 96e0f5be-8e7d-402d-b7d0-2ebadc745663
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=40.0.3}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:273)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:94)
    at twitter.main(twitter.java:10)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'U0138039-TPL-A', ip: '192.168.1.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/Users/u0138039/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8514896172902827974webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9982)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/Users/u0138039/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8514896172902827974webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12626)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/u0138039/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8514896172902827974webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12643)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/u0138039/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8514896172902827974webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12648)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/u0138039/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8514896172902827974webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12590)
```

please let me know how can i fix it.

Thaks

Comment: Exception is thrown when the element IS present in the DOM, but not visible. Take a screenshot of the current state before ``fd.findElement`` and see what FD actually sees. https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html

Comment: Try with the answer-

Comment: Please format the code in your question properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem I ran into is when I navigated to the site myself, the login panel was showing but when I did the same thing with code, the login panel was not showing. The way to get around that is to click on the "Log In" button, then enter the username/password. The code below clicks the Log In button and enters the email and password

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/?lang=en");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.StreamsLogin")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("signin-email")).sendKeys("email");
driver.findElement(By.id("signin-password")).sendKeys("password");
```

---

EDIT: For those who can't see the Log In button??? This is what I see.

[image]

Comment: Ah! i do not see any button with class name StreamsLogin!

Comment: @SIslam Added screenshot of Log In button location. This code runs and works for me. I'm not sure why you can't see the button???

Comment: Hi @JeffC, even i'm unable to see the login button. However, when i ran the code i got the following exception `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button.StreamsLogin"}
`

Comment: I can't see what you see... you'll have to take the code that I provided and update it based on what you see or use another's answer. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score -1):

I tried with [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) as below and it worked! It fills `user name` and `password` as `foo` and `bar` and `submits`.

```
package org;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TwitterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       // driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Go to the page
        driver.get("https://twitter.com/?lang=en");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);      
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='front-signin js-front-signin']")));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("document.getElementById('signin-email').value = 'foo';");
        js.executeScript("document.getElementById('signin-password').value = 'bar';");
        js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('t1-form signin')[0].submit();");
        wait.wait(10);

        driver.quit();    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using JSE? There is no need.

Comment: @JeffC Could you help on this i tried with wait and several locator (ID,Classname,Xpath) but did not able to get through-- Some rough snippet-http://pastebin.com/e3gMGYCG